# Sorting Child Related Rows Consecutively after Parent Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have a table thats like this

```
 ID   |   ParentID   |   Name
  1   |    NULL      |    A
  2   |    NULL      |    B
  3   |      1       |    C
```

How Would this be sorted so it returns like this

```
 ID   |   ParentID   |   Name
  1   |    NULL      |    A
  3   |      1       |    C
  2   |    NULL      |    B
```

Comment: what is logic in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afd6e/3/0). you can use the below query.

```
select * from test
order by coalesce(parentid,id)
```